# How to get the intersection pointers of a paper

Tags: opencv, image-processing, perspective, coordinate-transformation

I have photoed an A4 paper. I didn't take the whole 4 points, only with 2 or 3 points.

If there are 3 points in the photo, I can only get the coordinates of A,B,D and line CD. I can compute the intersection of CD and BC.
[photo with 3 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQP85.png)

But if there are 2 points in the photo, I've no idea how to compute the 3rd and 4th point.
[photo with 2 point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGIcc.png)
How can I compute the coordinate of the 4th point.

If I get the 4 points I can use the 4 points to take a perspective transformation with opencv(warpperspective) and rectify the picture.

Comment: Difficult - how do you know whether AB is the long or the short edge?

Comment: not really possible. you'd need to know a LOT more information about the photo, e.g. depth of field, field of view, blah blah blah.

Comment: @MarcB - I'm not sure that's true.  You have two coordinates and two angles (BAC and ABD).  Other than not knowing whether AB is the long or short edge, my intuition says this is doable (though I'm not going to attempt to wade through the maths to prove myself right/wrong ;)

Comment: I suppose AB is the short edge.  depth of field, field of view these information are unknown, I use phone to take the photo. I think edge AB, angles BAC and ABD is known, I can only get the intersection of AD and BC, cannot get the intersection of AB and CD... If there are 3 points in a photo, I can get two intersection by edge AB and CD, AD and BC. But if there are only 2 points in a photo, I think it's undoable.....

Comment: This is unresolvable problem. At least you need the slope of line CD to define the view angle. or there can be infinite numbers of angles and infinite papers.